# Pandas Dataframe Column Coding Before After Event - Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a datafame that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
            '2' , '2', '3', '3'], 
     'Year': ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015",
              "2016", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2013"], 
     'Event': ['0', '0', '0', '1','0', '0',
               '0', '1', '0']})
```

I want to create a new column where the values are centered around the event such that the time before the event is decreasing from 0, the time of the event is 0, and the time after the event is increasing from 0. In each case, time before and after the event would only be recorded for each ID. Some ID's do not have an event so they remain 0 and each event can only happen a maximum of one time for each ID.

I would like for the result to look like this:

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
            '2', '2', '3', '3'], 
     'Year': ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015",
              "2016", "2012", "2013", "2012",
              "2013"], 
     'Event': ['0', '0', '0', '1','0', '0',
               '0', '1', '0'], 
     'Period': ['-3', '-2', '-1', '0',
                '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']})
```

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is write a custom function called `get_period` that takes in a pd.Series where a specific event value occurs once (in your case, the string `'1'`), and returns a pd.Series integer range where `0` is at the same index where the event occurs.

For example, `get_period(pd.Series(['0','0','0','1','0']))` determines that the length of the series is `5`, locates `'1'` at index=3, then creates `np.arange(5) = [0,1,2,3,4]`, subtracts 3 from each value, and returns `pd.Series([-3,-2,-1,0,1])`.

Then we can perform a groupby `ID` on your DataFrame, and apply the  function `get_period` to the `Event` column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_period(s, event_value='1'):
    event_idx = np.where(s == event_value)[0]
    if len(np.where(s == event_value)[0]) == 0:
        return pd.Series([0]*len(s))
    else:
        return pd.Series(np.arange(len(s)) - event_idx)

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2' , '2', '3', '3'], 'Year': ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2013"], 'Event': ['0', '0', '0', '1','0', '0', '0', '1', '0']})
df['Period'] = df.groupby("ID").Event.apply(lambda x: get_period(x)).values
```

Result:

```
  ID  Year Event  Period
0  1  2012     0      -3
1  1  2013     0      -2
2  1  2014     0      -1
3  1  2015     1       0
4  1  2016     0       1
5  2  2012     0       0
6  2  2013     0       0
7  3  2012     1       0
8  3  2013     0       1
```

Comment: This was useful for the sample data but it doesn't work correctly in my full data and I'm not sure why. It mostly works but I end up with implausible periods like 6890 and sometimes the period is plausible but still incorrect

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of your full data where the method isn't working? I would be happy to try to figure out what's going wrong. is it possible that the event in your full data set is happening more than once due to some error in the data?

Comment: I think I found the problem... I ran a Mahalanobis matching procedure in Stata and it looks like it matched some treated firms against other treated firms, which it should not do. That made it so that my Event column has more than 1 event for each ID which is not what I want. Let me see if I can fix the matching procedure and try again!

Answer (score 1):

This is not so different from Derek )'s solution. But it's using pandas only.

```py
def get_period(x):
    if "1" in x["Event"].values:
        out = (x.index - 
               x[x["Event"].eq("1")].index[0]).values
    else:
        out = [0] * len(x)
    x["Period"] = out
    return x

df = df.groupby("ID").apply(fun)\
       .reset_index(drop=True)
df["Period"] = df["Period"].astype("int")
```

Comment: This was useful for the sample data but it doesn't work correctly in my full data and I'm not sure why. It mostly works but I end up with implausible periods like 6890 and sometimes the period is plausible but still incorrect